# Change selectbox dynamic in angular 4 formly

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on angular 4 and I am stuck in formly form.

I want to change a select box's options dynamically like when I get response from API and then the select box's options should be changed as per API response:

```
let fields: Array<FormlyFieldConfig> = [
  {
    className: 'row',
    fieldGroup: [
      {
                className: 'col-xs-12',
                type: 'select',
                key: 'documenttype',
                templateOptions: {
                    options: [{label:'One',value:'1'},{label:'two',value:'2'}],
                    label: 'selectbox',
                    placeholder: 'selectbox',
                },
            }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here is a plunker link: https://plnkr.co/edit/5VOGurddzHJFWn2Qz4Yx?p=preview

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really need to provide more information on what's Not working, and show more code

Comment: @Fredrik Lundin  I added plunker link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your just need to assign the new value into the field options,
see the example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tns2ve

Comment: Thank you so much @a.aitboudad for your effort and I really appreciate but I need to change options on button click

Answer (score 0):

**For Select2**

> You can do something like this:

**MarkUp:**

```
<select2 *ngIf="select2DataArray.length>0" [data]="select2DataArray"
     [value]="selectedOption">
</select2>
```

**Component function where you get data from API:**

```
this.select2DataArray = [];
setTimeout(() => {
   this.select2DataArray = data;
   this.selectedOption = 'select-2 option';
 },100);
```